# "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

Well, I was working on my pre-test and I found this problem came through my project. DO you know how to solve this> I've checked it both on the code and the tutorial videos and it exactly the same, but it went wrong when I tried to compile it.

```
<?php
    header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    header ("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    include "library/config.php";

    $postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $today    = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($postjson['aksi']=='add')
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($mysql, "INSERT INTO master_customer SET
        name_customer = '$postjson[name_customer]',
        desc_customer = '$postjson[desc_customer]',
        created_at = '$today'
        ");   

        $idcust = msqli_insert_id($mysqli);

        if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'customerid'=> $idcust));
        else $result = json_encode(array('succes'=>false));

        echo $result;
    }

?>
```

Comment: i'm a beginner, sir. Then, can you help me to solve it? this is my first time to use those syntax.

Comment: I would not recommend to learn MySQLi, bur rather start with PDO. It's easier.

Comment: Look at the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools. Make sure there's nothing being returned except the JSON result. There might be an error message.

Comment: The error message shown just like ERROR SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". But, I don't really know which sentence was wrong.